# Вычислить значение функции у, развив функцию cos(x) в ряде Тейлора

Tags: c++, c, функции

Нужно вычислить значение функции у, развив функцию cos(x) в ряде Тейлора. Аргумент х изменяется от –2 до 2 с шагом 0.5. Определить погрешность.
Я написал код, но на даном промежке он не работает правильно.
Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку.

Завдання:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h> 


double Coson(float x)
{
    float sum = x - 1;
    int i = 1;
    float t = 0.001;
    float member = x - 1;
    while (member > t)
    {
        member = member * (x - 1);
        sum += member / i;
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    float y, st = 0, x = -2, err = 0;
    float flag = 0;

    puts("===================================================");
    printf("     x             y          standart        error \n");
    puts("===================================================");
    for (x = -2; x <= 2; x += 0.5)
    {
        if (-1 <= x && x <= 0)
        {
            y = Coson(x / 2) - Coson(pow(x, 2));
            st = log(x / 2) - log(pow(x, 2));
            err = st - y;
        }
        else if (x > 0)
        {
            y = Coson(pow(cos(x / 2), 2) * cos(2 * x));
            st = log(pow(cos(x / 2), 2) * cos(2 * x));
            err = st - y;
        }
        else if (x <= 0)  
            flag = 1;
        if (flag == 0)
            printf("  %f     %f     %f      %f \n", x, y, st, err);
        else    
            printf("  %f     not define    \n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже, что в условие `if (flag == 0)` нужно менять на противоположное.

Comment: Может, не "развив", а "разложив" в ряд?...

Answer (score 1):

> Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку.

Ошибка на уровне программирования заключается в неправильном использовании переменной *flag*:

1. Раз вы проверяете её на равенство, то она должна быть типа *int* - вещественные переменные проверять на строгое равенство нельзя.
2. Вы инициализировали её значением "0" один раз - вне цикла. И это значение она просто-напросто **сохраняет** так как в условии *if* оно присваивается не во всех ветках. Т.е. присвоение происходит **не всегда**, поэтому оператор *flag = 0;* должен быть первым оператором цикла.

После внесения этих двух исправлений, выдача получилась такая:

```
===================================================
     x             y          standart        error 
===================================================
  -2.000000     not define    
  -1.500000     not define    
  -1.000000     -1.500000     -nan      -nan 
  -0.500000     -0.500000     -nan      -nan 
  0.000000     0.000000     -nan      -nan 
  0.500000     -0.492769     -0.678789      -0.186020 
  1.000000     -1.320496     -nan      -nan 
  1.500000     -1.530011     -nan      -nan 
  2.000000     -1.190816     -nan      -nan
```

Ясно, что с реализацией математики у Вас проблемы, но это уже - совсем другая история.